# Python linter vs PEP8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Nagios Scraper in Python3. I have Github set to automatically run checks (i.e. Python Linter) to make sure the code is good. It is currently failing that check, although the code **works**.

When I check with a [PEP8 checker online](http://pep8online.com/), I am getting constant warnings about `**line break before binary operator**. The [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) says I should put the operators at the beginning of the line.

Example of the "wrong" code:

```
for (a, b, c) in zip(user, url, extracted_information):
    data_to_print += (
        bcolors.OKGREEN + '{hosts_up}\t'
        + bcolors.FAIL + '{hosts_down}\t'
        + bcolors.WARNING + '{hosts_unreachable}\t'
    )
```

Which method is correct? Mine, the PEP8 checker, or something else?

Comment: To the close-voter: This code works as I expect it to.

Comment: But the code doesn't parse, due to a missing `)`!

Comment: Argh, you're right! I was expecting to put in the minimal amount of code to produce the warning. Is this better @AJNeufeld?

Comment: I know that pycodestyle, formerly known as pep8 - without a space, is incorrect, and does what you state. PEP 8 states that you are correct, ignore the linter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A linter doesn't check that the code *works,* it checks that the code follows some specific formatting guidelines.** Neither is more *correct,* but there is community consensus that *in general,* following the PEP8 standard makes Python code easier to read for humans.

It is completely possible that the online linter, which you haven't referenced or named, *contradicts* PEP8 in some way, in which case I would instead try using one of the well-maintained linters like [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/). Or make your life even simpler and use [Black](https://github.com/python/black) to automatically *format* your code and get most of PEP8 for free.

---

> line break before binary operator

Means just that: the linter considers it a problem that there is a line break (aka. newline) just before a binary operator (in this case, presumably `+`, although I didn't expect that to be considered a *binary* operator in a string context). Try moving the `+` operators from the start to the end of the previous line.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that PEP 8 [allows the usage of operators before or after a new line](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator), as long as it's consistent throughout.

Comment: This sounds like a bad joke, because pycodestyle - which flake8 wraps - has this error. Noice.

Comment: Added the link, but I understand what you're saying